# Python: Pandas Memory Error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather big dataset around 5287657 with around 15 columns. I was trying to create a pivot table and it gives me a `MemoryError` **when trying to create the DataFrame**.
The following is the eror message I am seeing:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 411, in __init__
  arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5472, in _to_arrays
  dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5500, in _list_to_arrays
  coerce_float=coerce_float)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5555, in _convert_object_array
  for arr in content]
File "inference.pyx", line 393, in pandas.lib.maybe_convert_objects (pandas\lib.c:32941)
MemoryError
```

Is there any limit on the data we can manipulate using Pandas before a memory error occurs?

Comment: do you need all the columns?  You can read in only the ones you need with the read_csv's `usecols=` option.

Comment: @monkut: I need all the columns and actually each column has 10 values so technically we are having around 150 columns.

Comment: I just watched this talk the other day, on server log analysis with pandas, and in it he mentions turning off garbage collection.  Seems a bit dubious to me, but it might help you.  http://pyvideo.org/video/1745/server-log-analysis-with-pandas-0

Comment: I think at the end of the video Wes suggests this was mainly because of the bespoke date parser being used in read_csv, I don't see how this would help in a pivot. How much memory in python using before the pivot?

Comment: @Andy:Python was using around 30-35MB of memory after reading the entire data set to a dictionary. Once I start the assigning the columns and rows to the pivot table, then memory starts increasing and it fails once it reaches approximately 1.72GB of Memory.

Comment: Interesting... could you share the code you are using to do the pivot? (Just so we're talking about the same thing.)

Comment: How are you reading them into a dictionary object? That part seems bad, you should try using `pd.read_csv` it'll be much much more efficient.

Comment: @Andy: I am opening the file and looping through each line and storing the required data in variables and then passing to the dictionary object for appending.

Comment: Don't do that! Use [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) to create your DataFrames, it has been heavily optimised for this task.

Comment: When I tried to use read_csv method the program crashes and when I see the error log it says the error is in parser module. Also, I am not sure if I can use read_csv method as I am reading multiple files and I am pivoting the data based upon that data from all files. My column names are the file names.

Comment: @buggsbunny4 but you are crashing before you pivot? At the moment you are reading in files into a dictionary the converting (these two steps are the memory inefficient bit), I'm suggesting creating a list of DataFrames first (then concating to one df).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to [analyse the data in chunks](http://www.pandas-docs.com/dev/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).
Another approach is to load a random sample of the data - I've written a short article about this - https://nikolaygrozev.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/fast-and-simple-sampling-in-pandas-when-loading-data-from-files/